# Solve the differential equation $y''- 2y' + y = e^{e^x}(e^x-1)^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Problem from Apostol's Calculus book volume 2. Find the general solution of the differential equation in the given interval.

$$\tag{1} y''-  2y' + y = e^{e^x}(e^x-1)^2$$

With $x \in (-\infty,+\infty)$. According to the book, the answer is

$$\tag{2}y = (A+Bx)e^x + e^{e^x} - xe^x\int e^{e^x}dx + e^x\int xe^{e^x}dx $$

Attempt:

I used the method of variation of parameters. First we have to find the solution of $y''-2y' + y = 0$, which are $e^x$ and $xe^x$. Now, the Wronskian matrix is

$$W(x) = \begin{bmatrix}
e^x & xe^x \\
e^x & e^x + xe^x 
\end{bmatrix} $$

Whose inverse is

$$W^{-1}(x) = \begin{bmatrix}
e^{-x} + xe^{-x} & -xe^{-x} \\
-e^{-x} & e^{-x} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we calculate

$$\begin{bmatrix} v_1(x) \\ v_2(x) \end{bmatrix} = \int e^{e^x}(e^x-1)^2 W^{-1}(x)\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}dx = \int e^{e^x}(e^x-1)^2\begin{bmatrix} -xe^{-x} \\ e^{-x} \end{bmatrix}dx = \int \begin{bmatrix} -xe^{e^x-1}(e^x-1)^2  \\ e^{e^x-1}(e^x-1)^2 \end{bmatrix}dx$$

Therefore, the solution is

$$y = (A+Bx)e^x + e^xv_1(x) + xe^xv_2(x)$$

$$\tag{3} y = (A+Bx)e^x -e^x\int xe^{e^x-1}(e^{2x}-2e^x+1)dx + xe^x\int e^{e^x-1}(e^{2x}-2e^x+1)dx $$

But I couldn't prove that $(3)$ is equal to $(2)$. Could someone help me?